# How do I increase token lifetime for daemon app on Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, access-token

*How do I increase token lifetime for daemon app on Azure B2C?*
I have problem finding correct setting on Azure Portal.

I am setting up Azure B2C security. Everything is fine, I have daemon app which acquires token, saves it to cache, and calls API which check tokens validity. Subsequent calls check token lifetime and if expired, silently gets new one.

I have a requirement that token lifetime has to be more than default 1 hour.

I have found how to increase token life time **for user-flow** under Azure AD B2C | User flows / policy/properties.

But daemon apps don't use user flows. Is there another place to configure this? Is it somewhere in manifest and have I missed it? Do I not understand deamon apps and client credentials flow correctly?

I am using recommended libraries described here https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki .

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the [lifetime of an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties-after-the-retirement) is 1 hour by default. If you want to customize the lifetime of the token (increase or decrease), you need to use powershell to [create a token lifetime policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes), and then assign the policy to the service principal to set the token lifetime.

However, as far as I know, B2C currently does [not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#current-limitations) daemon-based client credential flow.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have read the guide you have posted. I have expected some different way to set this up then by setting up custom policy using powershell console. I dont think that I will have the opportunity to verify this solution any day soon.